# How to hide one level for all collections with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

Using python how would I hide one level? Like shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Override the context.**

[image]
*Test run, collapses "Collection 1"*

To hide one level the operator used is  `bpy.ops.outliner.show_one_level(open=False)` enable developer tools in prefs to display [find link]

If we invoke an operator in outliner from mouse or button then the `context.area` is an outliner, if we run it from the text editor, for example, it's a text editor area.  The operator knows naught of the text editor area.

Overriding the context is a way to "fool" the operator into thinking it has been run from elsewhere or on a collection that is not context [add link]

Below is a test script.  I have hard coded in the default "Collection 1" to be collapsed.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
screen = context.screen
collection = context.collection
collection = bpy.data.collections["Collection 1"]
view_layer = context.view_layer

outliners = [a for a in screen.areas if a.type == 'OUTLINER']
c = context.copy()
c["collection"] = collection
for ol in outliners:
    c["area"] = ol

    bpy.ops.outliner.show_one_level(c, open=False)
    ol.tag_redraw()

#view_layer.update()
```